# Xcode Cannot symbolicate crash log in View Device Logs

Tags: xcode, crash, symbolicate

I installed my app into an iPhone via Xcode, then disconnect the iPhone from Mac, lauch the app ... crash.

Re-connect the iPhone to Mac, open Xcode > Devices > The iPhone > View Device Logs, but got the following result, it cannot symbolicate the crash in my code.

I also tried using the symbolicatecrash command, got the same result.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1c623b38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b8ab062 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1c623a80 +[NSException raise:format:] + 104
3   我的AppName                   0x00091410 0x89000 + 33808
4   我的AppName                   0x000d897a 0x89000 + 326010
5   我的AppName                   0x000d849a 0x89000 + 324762
6   我的AppName                   0x0009fb0c 0x89000 + 92940
7   我的AppName                   0x000dc9f6 0x89000 + 342518
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1bcf1792 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1bcf177e _dispatch_client_callout + 18
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bcf5d00 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 898
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1c5dfd64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1c5dde14 __CFRunLoopRun + 844
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1c5310ea CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 466
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1c530f0c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  GraphicsServices                0x1dcdbb3c GSEventRunModal + 76
16  UIKit                           0x218b5e7e UIApplicationMain + 146
17  我的AppName                   0x000bfe56 0x89000 + 224854
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x1bd1e4e6 _dyld_process_info_notify_release + 26
```

My build-settings:

```
Deployment Postproccessing         NO
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy    NO
Strip Linked Product               YES
Strip Style                        All Symbols
Debug Information Format           DWARF with dSYM File
Debug Information Level            Compiler default
Symbols Hidden by Default          NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find out the reason: the PRODUCT_NAME includes Chinese charactors ....